# Changing SciChart VerticalLineAnnotaton Label position

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

I'm using SciChart to show any charts. So I need to change a position of a label appears at the cross of VerticalLineAnnotation and chart. By default, it's at the MiddleRight position, I need to place it to TopLeft.

---

[image: VerticalLineAnnotation with Label to move]

Comment: Top left relative to the mouse? or top left of the chart?